# pass an array using onClick in js

Tags: javascript

So I have this code below. Whenever I click the button, it goes to the render_initialize_board and console.logs only the first element of the array fixed. How to pass the whole array to the function using onclick in javascript?

```
function render_initialize_board(N,fixed){
     console.log(fixed);
}

 N = 4;
 var fixed = [0,1,0,0]

  $("#header ul").append('<li><a href="#'+N+'" data-toggle="tab" onclick="render_initial_board('+N+','+fixed+')">'+ N +'</a></li>');
```

Comment: Consider using event listeners instead of attaching event handlers through HTML. Something like ``$("#header ul").append(`<li><a href="#${N}" data-toggle="tab">${N}</a></li>`); $("#header ul a").on('"click", function (e) { render_initialize_board(N, [0,1,0,0]); });``. It's hard to give a definitive answer since there is little context in the question. Providing a [mcve] will go a long way in getting the best answer.

Comment: If you concat a string and a non-string, JavaScript will call the `toString()` method of the non-string. Therefore `'render_initial_board('+N+','+fixed+')'` will be `'render_initial_board(4,0,1,0,0)'` since `arr.toString()` is equivalent to `arr.join(',')`.

Comment: Also, you wrote a function called `render_initialize_board`, but you called `render_initial_board`, which is not defined, in the `onclick`.

Comment: Just want to thank @HereticMonkey for giving me this insight. It actually solved my problem thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few too many quotes. With those quotes you are passing a string representation of the array to your function, which from its point of view looks like separate arguments for each element. You can just use:

```
onclick="render_initialize_board(N, fixed)"
```

```js
function render_initialize_board(N, fixed, fixed2) {
  console.log(fixed);
}

N = 4;
var fixed = [9, 1, 0, 0]

$("#header ul").append('<li><a href="#' + N + '" data-toggle="tab" onclick="render_initialize_board(N, fixed)">' + N + '</a></li>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  <ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By concatenating those strings and variables, the `fixed` array is being converted to a string.
Because of that, the function call looks like this when the click event is handled: `render_initialize_board(4, 0, 1, 0, 0)`

In that case, the `fixed` parameter does, in fact, equal 0.

To make it easier to read while avoiding the issue, just use jQuery's `click` method.

```
function render_initialize_board(N, fixed) {
  console.log(fixed);
}

var N = 4;
var fixed = [0, 1, 0, 0];

$("#header ul")
  .append('<li><a href="#' + N + '" data-toggle="tab">' + N + "</a></li>")
  .click(() => render_initialize_board(N, fixed)); // Replace "onclick" with this
```